# Moles 0.94 installation can't find pex.powertool.x64.msi

Tags: moles, pex

I'm trying to install the latest Moles/Pex 0.94, but the install is unable to uninstall the previous version because it cannot locate pex.powertool.x64.msi.  I searched for this file on multiple computers here, but can't seem to locate it anywhere.  Is this file available somewhere, or is there a way to manually remove pex/moles?

Comment: The solution was to run the version 0.92 install executable (en_visual_studio_2010_pex_0.92_power_tools_x64_538593.exe) from the command line with the /uninstall switch.

Comment: Post an answer to your own question! =)